# Fortran 90 rank mismatch in attempting to extract a vector from an array

Tags: fortran, extract, fortran90

In my Fortran 90 code, I have created the following array (called **array**) of integers:

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
```

I wish to extract the first column, and save it in a four-element vector called **time**.  I have the following code:

```
PROGRAM test
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: numrows=4, numcols=10
  INTEGER :: i, j, k
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: array, time

  ALLOCATE(array(numrows,numcols))
  ALLOCATE(time(numrows))

  k=1
  DO i=1,numrows
    DO j=1,numcols
      array(i,j)=k
      k=k+1
    END DO
  END DO

  DO i=1,numrows
    WRITE(*,"(100(3X,I3))") (array(i,j), j=1,numcols)
  END DO

  time=array(:,1)
END PROGRAM test
```

But, I get the following error message (when compiling in gfortran):

```
test.f90:8.15:

  ALLOCATE(time(numrows))
               1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (1/2)
test.f90:22.2:

  time=array(:,1)
  1
Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

Why is this the case?  The error message seems to suggest that the array `array(:,1)` is of rank 2, not rank 1.  Is there any way that I can convert `array(:,1)` to an array of rank 1?  Do I need to use `RESHAPE` to somehow squeeze the array?  Or is the problem that by using `array(:,1)`, I am specifying a column vector rather than a row vector?  Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying a rank-2 allocatable array called time:

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: array, time
```

and then attempting to allocate it as a rank-1 array:

```
  ALLOCATE(time(numrows))
```

-- don't do that.   This works perfectly fine:

```
PROGRAM test
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: numrows=4, numcols=10
  INTEGER :: i, j, k
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: array
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: time

  ALLOCATE(array(numrows,numcols))
  ALLOCATE(time(numrows))

  k=1
  DO i=1,numrows
    DO j=1,numcols
      array(i,j)=k
      k=k+1
    END DO
  END DO

  DO i=1,numrows
    WRITE(*,"(100(3X,I3))") (array(i,j), j=1,numcols)
  END DO

  time=array(:,1)
END PROGRAM test
```

Comment: Argh, I'm so silly. Thanks for your time, for pointing this out to me, and for your patience with me. I truly appreciate it.